# lot of records in html5 local storage?

Tags: html

1)  is it possible to store lot of records in html5 storage?

2)  what is the maximum size of local storage of HTML5?

3) can we  access local storage using RDBMS Concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Yes

2 -

> **Disk space**
>
> User agents should limit the total amount of space allowed for storage
>   areas.
>
> User agents should guard against sites storing data under the origins
>   other affiliated sites, e.g. storing up to the limit in
>   a1.example.com, a2.example.com, a3.example.com, etc, circumventing the
>   main example.com storage limit.
>
> User agents may prompt the user when quotas are reached, allowing the
>   user to grant a site more space. This enables sites to store many
>   user-created documents on the user's computer, for instance.
>
> User agents should allow users to see how much space each domain is
>   using.
>
> A mostly arbitrary limit of five megabytes per origin is recommended.
>   Implementation feedback is welcome and will be used to update this
>   suggestion in the future.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

3 -

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: can i create primary ,foriegh key ,multiple tables in HTML5 local storage?

Comment: @youCanCheatMe No. It's a key-value storage.

Comment: user-Agent means the size we baught in server for our website, am i right?

Comment: @youCanCheatMe No. Its the browser

Comment: is it possible to see all records by end user through viewsourcecode in browser? can i maintain secretly as MYSql?